# OpenIdConnect Owin login with google

Tags: asp.net, owin, google-openid, openid-connect

I'm trying to set up OWIN OpenIdConnect to authorize with google provider.

I have used:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/28/owin-security-components-in-asp-net-openid-connect.aspx

as a tutorial for that, but it's designed for Azure AD provider, so i changed necessary information to google:

Startup.Auth:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                Authority = "https://accounts.google.com",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/"
            });
    }
```

This causes redirect loop error in my browser.

To be sure, I have changed provider to Azure and it works perfectly.

Do you have idea how to fix that? In perfect I would like to integrate it with default membership provider, but for now I'm trying to get it work somehow.

*EDIT:*

I have found out that problem is in response_mode. Azure returns with POST, and google is returning GET.

Do you have any idea how to:

- Make google returns with POST
- Make OWIN OpenIdConnect read GET value property? Its separated from a url by '#', not '?'.

Comment: did you manage to resolve your problem?

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

OWIN OpenIdConnectHandler only supports POST.

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Doesn't specify response modes, so I am not sure if google+ signin does.

Answer (score 0):

I followed an alternative approch without OWIN, as I tried to avoid using a lot of different libraries.

I basically bult a lightweight implementation especially for authentication against google (see description / documentation):
http://www.dominikamon.com/articles/3091/oidc-lightweight-library-for-aspnet.html

I've uploaded the code to Github:
https://github.com/DominikAmon/Amon.cc.OIDC